# .NET Getting the correct IPEndpoint used by UdpClient for local computer?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, udp

We are creating a system using TCP for main communications and UDP for broadcasting. The clients broadcast their status while the server listens for their broadcasts and responds with an acknowledgment for the client to connect using the IPEndpoint of the received message. The problem here is when a server is created it gets an IP address from the Dns.GetHostAddresses() method and sets it as its IP and creates a TCP socket using that IP. The UdpClient however does its own thing and sends a different IPEndpoint on my computer (ex. Adapter 2), so when the client tries to connect to the TCP stream, the endpoint doesn't exist.

I'm not sure how to get the same IPEndpoint in these cases, as I am not sure how the UdpClient class returns it either. I am also not sure if I should just send the endpoint in the actual acknowledgment packet, but I shouldn't because the UdpReceiveResult supposedly should return the IPEndpoint of the server computer.

Here is an example of some of the code:

GetIP4Address:

```
    public static string GetIP4Address()
    {
        //Retrieve all ip addresses associated with this computer (like when you invoke "ipconfig" in cmd)
        IPAddress[] hostIpAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        //We want to look through all of the IP addresses and search for the IPv4 address and return it
        foreach (IPAddress ip in hostIpAddresses)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily.Equals(AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }

        //If it does not exist, we can assume we are offline and to return the localhost address
        return Constants.LOCAL_IP;
    }
```

UDP ReceivePacket Task:

```
private async Task<Tuple<Packet, IPEndPoint>> ReceivePacket(UdpClient con)
    {
      byte[] data;
      UdpReceiveResult result = await con.ReceiveAsync();
      data = result.Buffer;
      Packet packet = Packet.Deserialize(data);
      return new Tuple<Packet, IPEndPoint>(packet, result.RemoteEndPoint);
    }
```

Usage of ReceivePacket to initialize client/server (Handshake):

```
private async Task HandShake()
    {
        // We look for a server up to MAX_RETRY times.
        int retryCounter = 0;
        UdpClient broadcast = new UdpClient();

        // Here is why we need UPD to accomplish this task. Because we need to broadcast
        // over the network asking for a server
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, Constants.CONNECTION_PORT);

        // We need to send a SYN packet letting know to the server (If exists) that we are asking
        // for a handshake. We serialize the packet
        Packet synPacket = new Packet();
        synPacket.Flags = PacketFlag.SYN;
        byte[] rawSYNPacket = Packet.Serialize(synPacket);

        do
        {
            // Sending our "BROADCAST"
            broadcast.Send(rawSYNPacket, rawSYNPacket.Length, endPoint);
            txtMessagesBox.Text += $"Waiting a server #{retryCounter}\n";

            // We wait for a response on a separate thread.
            // The receive method is a blocking operation so we wrote an extension method to
            // create an asynchronous method with a timeout.
            var packetTuple = await ReceivePacket(broadcast).WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SEARCH_SERVER_TIMEOUT));

            // If no packet is received we try it one more time up to MAX_RETRY times
            if (packetTuple == null)
            {
                ++retryCounter;
                continue;
            }
            // If we receive an ACK packet then a server exists and we need to configure the application as client
            else if (packetTuple.Item1.Flags == PacketFlag.ACK)
            {
                this.StartClient(packetTuple.Item2);
                return;
            }
        }
        while (retryCounter < MAX_RETRY);

        // If no response then the application must be configured as a server
        txtMessagesBox.Text += "Ok, I'll be the server\n";
        this.StartServer();
    }
```

I need to know how we can get these IPEndpoints to match up so the client can connect to the server when it receives a response.

Comment: Make sure your TCP server is listening on the same local IP(s) that your UDP server is listening on for the broadcasts. And make sure the UDP server is sending each ack using the same local IP that a broadcast was received on. It sounds like you are not doing all of that correctly, but you did not show any of the server-side code.

Comment: My problem is that I dont know how to use the same local IP that the UDP server is listening on because I am never actually binding the UDPClient to an IPEndPoint

Comment: And that is your problem. **On the server side**, you need to bind the UDP listener to the same IP that the TCP server is *bound* to. When that UDP listener receives a broadcast, it knows the IP endpoint it is listening on, and it knows the sender's IP endpoint. Send the ACK back to the sender using the same UDP object that received the broadcast. When the sender receives the ACK, the remote endpoint will be that of the UDP listener that sent the ACK, and by extension will be the corresponding TCP server. If the TCP server is bound to multiple IPs, create a separate UDP listener for each IP.